# How to generate a copy of an ObjectSet with not-managed objects?

Tags: .net, orm, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I want to get all the data of an ObjectSet (something like getAllProducts()) but this data should only be read, so if somebody uses an object taken from that collection, he modifies only the objects on the collection and not ObjectContext managed objecs or data at persistence engine.

I've read that detach stops the context to maintain tracking info. Also, I've read that detaching can consume a lot of system resources.

What can I do? I want a copy of a collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct - ObjectContext.Detach removes the object from the ObjectStateManager. This actually REDUCES the amount of memory used.

The following considerations apply when detaching objects:

- Detach only affects the specific object passed to the method. If the object being detached has related objects in the object context, those objects are not detached.
- In an independent association, the relationship information is not maintained for a detached object.
- Object state information is not maintained when an object is detached. This includes tracked changes and temporary key values.
- Detaching objects does not affect data in the data source.
- Cascade delete directives and referential constraints in an identifying relationship are not enforced during a detach operation.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271.aspx) for more info.

Brian

Comment: How to detach the related objects also?

Comment: Ugh - I don't know of an easy way to do it.  I believe you'd have to iterate through the collections and detach each object.